# DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated

Tags: node.js, angular, express, angular-fullstack

I am deploying my angular application on tomcat server. I have run the `ng build --prod` command and copied my `dist` folder on the server. Before accessing the page from the server, I wanted to test the app for myself on the localhost. When I try to run the command `http-server ./dist` then, it throws the following error:

```
(node:8788) [DEP0066] DeprecationWarning: OutgoingMessage.prototype._headers is deprecated
```

Does anybody know how to fix this? I have tried searching on the web and all the answers are either obsolete or not working. EDIT: Editing this again, so that somebody can answer. EDIT: Anybody?

Comment: As the error message itself suggests on the next line ("(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)"), try running with `--trace-deprecation` to get a stacktrace that indicates which package is actually using the deprecated API; you may need to find out the actual `node ..` command that runs from `http-server` invocation, and re-run it with the above flag

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding `app.disable('x-powered-by');` after `var app = express();` and then re-running this command: `ng build --prod`

Answer (score 0):

Better upgrade your Angular version.
This warning mostly comes from your old version package which is using private  property `._headers`.
My case is that I'm using Express under v15.
Express document v15 said that they no longer use private method `res._headers`.